# Space in ToC between frontmatter chapters and mainmatter chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, front-matter

I'm using the class memoir. I'm wondering if it's possible to have a ToC like this:

```
 Abstract .............................  i
 List of Figures ...................... iv
 List of Tables .......................  v

   ^
   | increase the size
   v

 1 XXXXXX .............................  1

 2 XXXXXX .............................  2
```

Is memoir enable to have a special space between chapters from the frontmatter and chapters from mainmatter? I read the user guide but I couldn't find anything relevant.

[EDIT: an example of code]

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \begin{document}

 \frontmatter

 \chapter{Abstract}
 \lipsum[23-24]
 \cleardoublepage
 \tableofcontents*
 \clearpage
 \listoffigures
 \clearpage
 \listoftables

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{Test Chapter One}
 \section{Section One One}
 \section{Section One Two}

 \chapter{Test Chapter Two}
 \section{Section Two One}
 \section{Section Two Two}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Preview of the code]

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a solution

The idea is to redefine `\mainmatter` to add space in ToC

```
 \documentclass{memoir}

 \let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
 \renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{30pt}}%
  \oldmainmatter%
 }

 \begin{document}

 \frontmatter

 \chapter{Abstract}
 \cleardoublepage
 \tableofcontents*
 \clearpage
 \listoffigures
 \clearpage
 \listoftables

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{Test Chapter One}
 \section{Section One One}
 \section{Section One Two}

 \chapter{Test Chapter Two}
 \section{Section Two One}
 \section{Section Two Two}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution; if you load the `etoolbox` package, you can do more simply `\preto{\mainmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{30pt}}}`